# How to find unit test dll in Azure Devops when copying test artifact to run on multiple agents (YAML)

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml

I am using Azure Devops YAML build pipeline for the build and test of my SQL SSDT project. I am trying to amend my YAML code so that the test part will run on multiple Microsoft hosted agents (I have purchased 2). When I run the VSTest task as part of the first job that is run on the single agent, it runs no problems. However, when I run it as part of the second job, the unit tests do not run, with an error saying it cannot find the requisite test files. Is there something I need to add to my second job to make this work?

Many thanks.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - stage
    - master

pr:
- master
- stage
- develop


pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'


jobs:
- job: BuildPublish
  steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '2.*'

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        restoreDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DIP_UsqlSln/packages'
    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '**/*.sln'
        msbuildArgs: '/p:USQLSDKPath=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/DIP_UsqlSln/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.USQL.SDK.1.4.190703/build/runtime;USQLTargetType=SyntaxCheck;DataRoot=$(Build.SourcesDirectory) /p:EnableDeployment=true'## Heading ##
        createLogFile: true
        logFileVerbosity: 'detailed'

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      inputs:
        Contents: '**'
        TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
        CleanTargetFolder: true
        OverWrite: true
      
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
        publishLocation: 'Container'

- job: Test
  dependsOn: BuildPublish
  strategy:
    parallel: 2
  steps:
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
    inputs:
      artifactName: 'drop'

  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      runOnlyImpactedTests: true
      runInParallel: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to find unit test dll in Azure Devops when copying test artifact to run on multiple agents (YAML)

That because the default **Destination directory** for the task DownloadBuildArtifacts is `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)`, however, the default **Search folder** for Visual Studio Test task is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`.

[image]

[image]

When you use the those two task in the build pipeline, **the value of those two predefined variables are not same**:

The value of `$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)` should be **`C:\agent\_work\r1\a`**.

The value of `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` should be **`c:\agent_work\1\s`**.

So, it will cause this issue, could not found the requisite test files.

To resolve this issue, we just need to change the default value of those two predefined variables to use same value:

```
- task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0

  displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'

  inputs:

    artifactName: drop

    downloadPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Or

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
      platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      searchFolder: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
      runOnlyImpactedTests: true
      runInParallel: true
```

Hope this helps.